# Pass slug or id on GET request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to test an API view for my Django project:

```
BOOK_URL = reverse('api:book') // '/api/book/'
book_id = 1

res = APIClient().get(f'BOOK_URL${book_id}/')
```

This works, but as you can see I need to interpolate the book_id into the string. Is there a way I can send a request without interpolating?

I tried:

```
res = APIClient().get(BOOK_URL, data={'book_id': book_id})
```

This is my views.py

```
class BookView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, book_id):

        book = get_object_or_404(
            Book.objects.all(),
            id=book_id
        )

        return book
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do (and you should do at least) is to use the `reverse` (`django.url.reverse`) to get the URL endpoint for the detail URL from view name and URL keyword arguments (like you're doing for the list URL).

For example:

```
url = reverse('api:book', kwargs={'book_id': book_id})
```

Assuming the URL keyword argument is `book_id`.

The default keyword argument is `pk` (takes the value of viewset's `lookup_field` if you don't set `lookup_url_kwarg`); so for `pk` this would be:

```
url = reverse('api:book', kwargs={'pk': book_id})
```